# Naming Convention for Blackberry Development

Tags: blackberry, java-me, naming-conventions, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have gone through with some of the sample examples of blackberry.

And in some classes I have found some variables are starting with _ like **`_address`** and some of them are ALLCAPS.

It is a bit different than the basic Java naming conventions.  Is there any difference between Java and BlackBerry naming convention?

Comment: Here is a link to the Sun's Java Coding Conventions. http://java.sun.com/docs/codeconv/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's just like any other company or person - everyone has their own coding style and you're just seeing the coding style of the RIM engineers who put together the sample apps.  I don't know if RIM has a formal internal code style guide, but they haven't published or recommended one to developers.

I would say just stick with the conventions and code style you already use for regular Java apps.